# Phaser 3 - Unable to decode audio data

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, phaser-framework

I'm trying to load an audio, but it gives an error to do the decoding. I tried different audios and different file types. I'm using Chrome, but in Edge it also gave the same error and Mozila gave another error.

Error

```
Error decoding audio: beginSound -  Failed to execute 'decodeAudioData' on 'BaseAudioContext': Unable to decode audio data.
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'decodeAudioData' on 'BaseAudioContext': Unable to decode audio data
```

preload file

```
class Load extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super({ key: 'load', active: true })
  }

  init() {}

  preloadScene() {}

  preload() {
    // Images
    // for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    //   this.load.image('road'+i, require('~/assets/game/assets/road-2.png'))
    // }

    this.load.audio('beginSound', '~/assets/game/assets/sounds/music.mp3')

    // Images
    // this.load.image(
    //   'scoreboard',
    //   require('~/assets/game/assets/scoreboard.png')
    // )
    // // Sprite sheet
    // this.load.spritesheet(
    //   'oilBar',
    //   require('~/assets/game/assets/oilBar.png'),
    //   {
    //     frameWidth: 220,
    //     frameHeight: 65,
    //   }
    // )
    // this.load.spritesheet('life', require('~/assets/game/assets/life2.png'), {
    //   frameWidth: 190,
    //   frameHeight: 65,
    // })
    // this.load.spritesheet('road', require('~/assets/game/assets/road.png'), {
    //   frameWidth: 640,
    //   frameHeight: 152,
    // })
    // this.load.spritesheet('pack', require('~/assets/game/assets/packs.png'), {
    //   frameWidth: 100,
    //   frameHeight: 100,
    // })
    // this.load.spritesheet(
    //   'player',
    //   require('~/assets/game/assets/player.png'),
    //   {
    //     frameWidth: 150,
    //     frameHeight: 300,
    //   }
    // )
    // this.load.spritesheet('enemy1', require('~/assets/game/assets/enemy.png'), {
    //   frameWidth: 150,
    //   frameHeight: 300,
    // })
    // this.load.spritesheet(
    //   'enemy2',
    //   require('~/assets/game/assets/enemy-2.png'),
    //   {
    //     frameWidth: 150,
    //     frameHeight: 300,
    //   }
    // )
    // if (!this.sys.game.device.os.desktop) {
    //   this.load.atlas(
    //     'buttons',
    //     require('~/assets/game/assets/buttons.png'),
    //     require('~/assets/game/assets/buttons.json')
    //   )
    // }
    // Loading text
    // let loadingText = this.add.text(
    //   20,
    //   this.cameras.main.centerY + 60,
    //   'Carregando: 100.00%',
    //   { fontSize: '26px', fill: '#FFF' }
    // )
    // Progress bar
    // this.graphicsProgressBar = this.add.graphics()
    // this.graphicsProgressBar.fillStyle(0xffffff, 1)
    // this.graphicsProgressBar.fillRectShape(
    //   new Phaser.Geom.Rectangle(
    //     20,
    //     this.cameras.main.centerY,
    //     this.game.config.width - 40,
    //     50
    //   )
    // )
    // Progress bar fill
    // this.graphicsProgressBarFill = this.add.graphics()
    // this.graphicsProgressBarFill.fillStyle(0x3587e2, 1)
    // this.graphicsProgressBarFill.fillRectShape(
    //   new Phaser.Geom.Rectangle(
    //     25,
    //     this.cameras.main.centerY + 5,
    //     this.game.config.width - 50,
    //     40
    //   )
    // )
    // Events
    // this.load.on('progress', this.updateBar, {
    //   graphicsProgressBarFill: this.graphicsProgressBarFill,
    //   loadingText: loadingText,
    //   cameraY: this.cameras.main.centerY,
    //   progressBarWidth: this.game.config.width - 50,
    // })
    // this.load.on('complete', this.complete, {
    //   scene: this.scene,
    // })
  }

  updateBar(percentage) {
    // Progress bar fill
    this.graphicsProgressBarFill.clear()
    this.graphicsProgressBarFill.fillStyle(0x009a93, 1)
    this.graphicsProgressBarFill.fillRectShape(
      new Phaser.Geom.Rectangle(
        25,
        this.cameraY + 5,
        percentage * this.progressBarWidth,
        40
      )
    )

    // Text
    percentage = percentage * 100
    this.loadingText.setText('Carregando: ' + percentage.toFixed(2) + '%')
  }

  complete() {
    this.scene.remove('load')
    this.scene.start('start')
  }

  create() {
    // Audio
    // const asyncLoader = (loaderPlugin) => {
    //   return new Promise((resolve) => {
    //     loaderPlugin
    //       .on('filecomplete', () => resolve())
    //       .on('loaderror', () => resolve())
    //     loaderPlugin.start()
    //   })
    // }
    // await asyncLoader(
    // )
    // this.load.audio('playSound', '~/assets/game/assets/sounds/play.mp3')
    // this.load.audio('crashSound', '~/assets/game/assets/sounds/crash.mp3')
    // this.load.audio('getOilSound', '~/assets/game/assets/sounds/get-oil.mp3')
    // this.load.audio('gameOverSound', '~/assets/game/assets/sounds/game-over.mp3')
  }

  update() {}
}

export default Load
```

Below I will leave the global settings of the game

```
game: {
        width: 380,
        height: 640,
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        dom: {
          createContainer: true,
        },
        physics: {
          default: 'arcade',
        },
        scene: [Load, Start, Instructions, Play, End],
      },
```

From the preload file, comment out all the code to test if something was conflicting.
About the path, I tested other ways to call the file and it didn't work either.

Version
Nuxt:"^2.15.8", Phaser:"^3.55.2"

Comment: Just for future reference you should only post the **minial code** needed to show the problem. like defined in [this Stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If that is not possible atleast remove the commented code. That makes helping easier for everybody.

Comment: I'm not sure where you call your phaser code into Nuxt, but the error suggests that the code is being called from the server-side. Hence, since you don't have audio on Node-like environments, you get this error.